# MSMQ accesing database in trigger

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, com, msmq

I have a MSMQ trigger configured as COM object. The trigger gets initiated and everything works fine if I am not accessing database. If I try to access database inside this function the trigger fails. So what is the possible cause for this? Is it due to the inappropriate user permission for anything? If so please say the rectification method.

Comment: In what way does the trigger fail? Is an error message emitted?  If so, what is it?

Comment: When you are connecting to the database, how are you supplying credentials?  Are you using SQL Authentication or Integrated Authentication?

Comment: I use SQL authentication. Now i am using Entity framework inside my trigger to access my databse.

Comment: In administartive eventes i could see this error. " The action defined by the rule ׈㽉ù with the ID ꯘ㽉ù was not invoked. The COM object may not be registered, or the executable file may not exist in your path. Error 0xc00e0e0b:"